# Facebook - FQL : Find where my friends have travelled

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I currently have the following query for where my friends have checkin. What I really want is to know where they have travelled to. So locations maybe 50-100km outside of their hometown. How can I make a query that will limit the results to locations outside my hometown and friends checkin locations outside of their hometowns.

```
{
    "q1" : "SELECT coords, author_uid FROM checkin WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())"
}
```

Comment: This is not possible imho with one FQL statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this particular problem was to find which friends have been around a given destination.

```
"SELECT author_uid FROM location_post " +
    "WHERE (author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) " +
    "OR tagged_uids IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())) " +
    "AND distance(latitude, longitude, \"*\", \"*\") < 10000";
```